# Cannot convert value of type [com.sun.proxy.$ProxyXX ScopedObject

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am getting this error when a bean of my project is initializated:

```
Could not convert constructor argument value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42] to required type [org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader]
```

This MultiResourceItemReader is a property of a FlatFileItemReader. In other spring batch jobs I have it the same without problems, but I can't localize the cause of the proxy conversion here. This is the bean definition of the linemapper.:

```
<bean id="updateStateBlocksReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="strict" value="false" />
    <property name="recordSeparatorPolicy" ref="skipBlankLinesPolicy" />
    <property name="comments">
        <array value-type="java.lang.String">
            <value>HEADER</value>
            <value>FOOTER</value>
        </array>
    </property>
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="com.telefonica.gest.jt.nuc.myjob.reader.MyCustomLineMapper">
            <constructor-arg ref="updateStateBlocksMultiReader" /> *****----> Error line
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="delimiter" value=";" />             
                    <property name="names" value="field1,field2" /> 
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                    <property name="prototypeBeanName" ref="readerDTO" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- This is the MultiResourceItemReader used as argument in the constructor of the lineMapper (To extract the current fileName) -->
<bean id="updateStateBlocksMultiReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="resources" value="file:#{jobExecutionContext['PATH_IN']}/#{jobExecutionContext['FILENAME_IN']}"/>
    <property name="delegate" ref="updateStateBlocksReader"/>
</bean>
```

I tried adding a StepScope bean with a proxyTargetClass property setted to "true" but not works. Finally I leave here the java of "MyCustomLineMapper.java" so you can see the constructor:

```
public class MyCustomLineMapper<T> implements LineMapper<BaseDTO>, InitializingBean  {

        private LineTokenizer tokenizer;
        private BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<BaseDTO> fieldSetMapper;
        private MultiResourceItemReader<T> delegator;
        
        public MyCustomLineMapper(final MultiResourceItemReader<T> delegator) {
             this.delegator = delegator;
        }
        
        public BaseDTO mapLine(final String line, final int lineNumber) throws Exception {
...
```

I am tried moving the bean scopes and config the proxyTargetclass property without effect. Not sure how continue with this. Sorry my bad english and Thanks.

Comment: You should be programming to the interface `ItemReader` not the concrete class. You get a proxy due to the step-scope.

Comment: I have the same CustomeLineMapperClass in other project passing a same MultiResourceReader too and works fine. I thinks in some moment the other project disable the proxy conversions but I dont't find where

Comment: They didn't. Yours is clearly marked as `scope="step"` which will generate a proxy. This by default is an interface based proxy and thus the object cannot be cast to `MultiResourceItemReader` but only a `ItemReader`. Hence the suggestion to program to the `ItemReader` interface which will make it work with anything or switch to class based proxies (which can lead to other difficulties). . Although I find it weird you need your `LineMapper` to have access to the `ItemReader` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, really work using ItemReader. I use the reader in the linemapper to log the current file that can fail when tokenize is executed. Can you recommend me some book or articles about this proxy system? I want learn better how this works

Comment: With this code you actually crated a circular dependency which might cause trouble later on.